# How to identify pairs of rows within a group in R?

Tags: r

I am wondering how to identify pairs in a table. The pair is defined by a set of columns with the same information in the row, but in one of the columns, the information of both rows differ. It may also differs for other columns as well. See the example below:

```
a1 <- c(100,110,100,200,105,110) 
a2 <- c(10,5,10,50,10,5)
a3 <- c(1,1,5,3,1,4)
a4 <- c('A','B','A','C','B','B')
a5 <- c('car blue','bus red','car blue','bicycle','bus red','bus red')
a6 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1)
A <- data.frame(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6)
```

In this example, there are two pairs: rows (1,3) and (2,6). You can see that all the information in the columns a1, a2, a4 and a5 are the same for the pairs, whereas the last column contains a different information defined by the category 0 and 1. The column a3 is also different but it does not define the pair. The pair is determined when one of them has 0 in the last column and the other one has 1. It is possible that we find a fake pair, with the same information for the 5 columns but being both with the category 0 (or both 1) in the last column. These ones I want to remove. So, can you help me with this? According to the example above, I need to find the corresponding table

```
b1 <- c(100,110,100,110)
b2 <- c(10,5,10,5)
b3 <- c(1,1,5,4)
b4 <- c('A','B','A','B')
b5 <- c('car blue','bus red','car blue','bus red')
b6 <- c(0,0,1,1)
B <- data.frame(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6)
```

Can you help me with that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your statement *"information in the first 5 columns are the same"* is not right: in (1,3), `a3` has values 1 and 5, similarly (2,6) are different.

Comment: One of the columns may have different information but this difference does not determine the pair. I have edited my message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do it these ways.

### base R

```r
A[ave(A$a6, A[,c("a1","a2","a4","a5")], FUN = function(z) all(0:1 %in% z)) > 0,]
#    a1 a2 a3 a4       a5 a6
# 1 100 10  1  A car blue  0
# 2 110  5  1  B  bus red  0
# 3 100 10  5  A car blue  1
# 6 110  5  4  B  bus red  1
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
A %>%
  group_by(a1, a2, a4, a5) %>%
  filter(all(0:1 %in% a6)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 6
#      a1    a2    a3 a4    a5          a6
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
# 1   100    10     1 A     car blue     0
# 2   110     5     1 B     bus red      0
# 3   100    10     5 A     car blue     1
# 4   110     5     4 B     bus red      1
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
> as.data.table(A)[, .SD[all(0:1 %in% a6),], by = .(a1, a2, a4, a5)]
    a1 a2 a4       a5 a3 a6
1: 100 10  A car blue  1  0
2: 100 10  A car blue  5  1
3: 110  5  B  bus red  1  0
4: 110  5  B  bus red  4  1
```

---

Data

```r
A <- structure(list(a1 = c(100, 110, 100, 200, 105, 110), a2 = c(10, 5, 10, 50, 10, 5), a3 = c(1, 1, 5, 3, 1, 4), a4 = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "B"), a5 = c("car blue", "bus red", "car blue", "bicycle", "bus red", "bus red"), a6 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: @user17841038, I've updated the answer to reflect change in logic (ignore `a3`).

Comment: The option dplyr works very well!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @r2evans I tested your dplyr answer and it will no work well when an group has more than 2 rows (a duplicate of either 0 or 1 in a6).  though I admit that seems contrived considering the sample data and discussion.

Comment: Very good point. I think resolving that would require some clarity from the OP. Thanks, @DPH!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is using duplicated(), but remember that it does not consider the first (or the last) as a duplicate. So using it once with and once without `fromLast = T` you get all duplicates.

```
cols <- c("a1", "a2", "a4", "a5")
A[all(0:1 %in% a6) & (duplicated(A[cols]) | duplicated(A[cols], fromLast = T)), ]

   a1 a2 a3 a4       a5 a6
1 100 10  1  A car blue  0
2 110  5  1  B  bus red  0
3 100 10  5  A car blue  1
6 110  5  4  B  bus red  1
```

Comment: This does not account for the need for both `0` and `1` in the last column.

Comment: Fair enough but you could filter afterwards on sum is 1 and count is 2. I would surely favor your data.table solution.

Comment: Added that part

Answer (score 0):

an optional `dplyr` approach can be this:

```
A %>%
    # build the groupings
    dplyr::group_by(a1, a2, a4, a5) %>%
    # select those  groups with exactly two rows, given that theire A6 sum is equal to 1 
    dplyr::filter(n() == 2 & sum(a6) == 1 & a6 %in% 0:1) %>%
    # good practise is to ungroup to avoid unwanted behaviour down stream
    dplyr::ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 x 6
     a1    a2    a3 a4    a5          a6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
1   100    10     1 A     car blue     0
2   110     5     1 B     bus red      0
3   100    10     5 A     car blue     1
4   110     5     4 B     bus red      1
```

Comment: This does not account *well* for the need for both `0` and `1` in the last column. For instance, `-1` and `2` would pass your test (though I admit that seems contrived considering the sample data and discussion).

Comment: @r2evans I have included aditional criteria in the filter to make sure we only have 0 and 1